# Use Three20 URL-based Navigation with PureMVC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, puremvc

is anybody already using Three20 URL-based Navigation with PureMVC?

I am not sure where to implement the URL mapping. In the AppDelegate, Faceade, RootViewController?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You set up the initial and regularly used URL mappings in the AppDelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching function.

```
TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
  TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
  [map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
  [map from:@"tt://catalog" toViewController:[CatalogController class]];
```

You can add and remove URLs from the URL map at any time by doing the following:

```
[[TTNavigator navigator].URLMap from:@"tt://post" toViewController:self selector:@selector(post:)];

[[TTNavigator navigator].URLMap removeURL:@"tt://post"];
```

Answer (score 0):

But why doesnt this work:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[TTNavigator navigator] viewControllerForURL:@"tt://post"]; 
[facade registerMediator:[BlogTableViewMediator withViewComponent:vc]];
```